# Ajax Calls Web API With Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, forms-authentication

We have been working on an asp.net web application and we have implemented the Forms Authentication in the application. Recently we get requirements to expose some features of the application for other systems. So we are planning to develop the Web API for this application. We need to host those Web APIs under the same IIS web application and we need to make them secure. So I added the `[Authorize]` attribute to the Web API Controller class.

Now I am confused here about its security. If we keep Forms Authentication, then how can I get my external system calls to be authenticated? Or Do I need to use some other authentication mechanism (e.g: OAuth) But will that work within the same application where we have Forms Authentication? I also enable the CORs on the API Controller class. The confusion is only about the security mechanism.

We have angular application and a native mobile app to use those APIs. Angular App is hosted separately in the IIS and Mobile App is running on IOS and Android.

Please suggest the solution as I am not sure which direction I should move.

Regards,
Jamil

Comment: Have you heard about jwt (Json web token) authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow this article [Mixing MVC + Web API Authentication (Using Forms Auth + Basic Auth)](https://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/23/mixing-mvc-forms-authentication-and-web-api-basic-authentication/).

In Short, for the external systems, to authenticate to the WebAPI, Forms Auth can't be used, we have to use Basic Auth Or OAuth. OAuth can't be mixed with Form Auth unless the whole application upgraded to use OAuth, but by defining the SecurityFilter for the Web API, we can keep Forms Authentication working in the web application and parallel to that we can define Basic Authentication Security which will use Basic Authentication or Any other authentication mechanism that we can use.

For me, this solution works.

1. I create a web API controller in the web form project.
2. By default, since the Forms Authentication is enabled at the whole site level using Web.Config. This new controller also secured using the Forms Authentication. To skip that security, I added a location tag in the web config and allow all users to access the web API path.

   ```
   <location path="api">
       <system.web>
           <authorization>
               <allow users="*" />
           </authorization>
       </system.web>
   </location>
   ```
3. Next, I define the security filter class and implement my own logic for authentication and authorization for the request.

   ```
   public class BasicAuthenticationIdentity : GenericIdentity
   {
       public BasicAuthenticationIdentity(string name, string password)
           : base(name, "Basic")
       {
           this.Password = password;
       }

       /// 
       /// Basic Auth Password for custom authentication
       /// 
       public string Password { get; set; }
   }

   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
   public class BasicAuthenticationFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
   {
       bool Active = true;

       public BasicAuthenticationFilter()
       { }

       ///
       /// Overriden constructor to allow explicit disabling of this
       /// filter's behavior. Pass false to disable (same as no filter
       /// but declarative)
       ///
       ///
       public BasicAuthenticationFilter(bool active)
       {
           Active = active;
       }

       ///
       /// Override to Web API filter method to handle Basic Auth check
       ///
       ///
       public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           if (Active)
           {
               var identity = ParseAuthorizationHeader(actionContext);
               if (identity == null)
               {
                   Challenge(actionContext);
                   return;
               }

               if (!OnAuthorizeUser(identity.Name, identity.Password, actionContext))
               {
                   Challenge(actionContext);
                   return;
               }

               var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

               Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

               // inside of ASP.NET this is required
               //if (HttpContext.Current != null)
               //    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

               base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
           }
       }

       ///
       /// Base implementation for user authentication - you probably will
       /// want to override this method for application specific logic.
       /// 
       /// The base implementation merely checks for username and password
       /// present and set the Thread principal.
       /// 
       /// Override this method if you want to customize Authentication
       /// and store user data as needed in a Thread Principle or other
       /// Request specific storage.
       ///

       protected virtual bool OnAuthorizeUser(string username, string password, HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
               return false;

           return true;
       }

       ///
       /// Parses the Authorization header and creates user credentials
       ///
       protected virtual BasicAuthenticationIdentity ParseAuthorizationHeader(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           string authHeader = null;
           var auth = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
           if (auth != null && auth.Scheme == "Basic")
               authHeader = auth.Parameter;

           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader))
               return null;

           authHeader = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader));

           var tokens = authHeader.Split(':');
           if (tokens.Length < 2)
               return null;

           return new BasicAuthenticationIdentity(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
       }

       ///
       /// Send the Authentication Challenge request
       ///
       void Challenge(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           var host = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.DnsSafeHost;
           actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
           //actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateUserNoAccessResponse();
           actionContext.Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", string.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", host));
       }
   }
   ```

   ```
   public class MyBasicAuthenticationFilter : BasicAuthenticationFilter
   {
       public MyBasicAuthenticationFilter()
       { }

       public MyBasicAuthenticationFilter(bool active)
           : base(active)
       { }

       protected override bool OnAuthorizeUser(string username, string password, HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           return true;
           //MembershipHelper Members = new MembershipHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);

           //if (Members.Login(username, password))
           //{
           //    // Here you can also check against a specific member type or member group

           //    Members.Logout();
           //    return true;
           //}
           //return false;
       }
   }

   [MyBasicAuthenticationFilter]
   [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
   public class TestController : ApiController
   {
       public List<string> Get()
       {
           return new List<string>() { "Value 1", "Value 2" };
       }
   }
   ```

   ```
   var authHeaders = {};
   authHeaders.Authorization = 'Basic ' + atob(username + ":" + password);
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:49501/api/values",
      type: "GET",
      headers: authHeaders,
      success: function (response) {
      }
   });
   ```